# For random variable $X$: $\mathbb{E}|X| < \infty$. Does it imply that for every $a \in \mathbb{R}$ there exists $\mathbb{E} | X - a | < \infty$?

Tags: probability, integration, probability-theory, expected-value

For random variable $X$ we know that: $\mathbb{E}|X| < \infty$ does it imply that for every $a \in \mathbb{R}$ there exists $\mathbb{E} | X - a | < \infty$?

Edit:

In general we know that: $\ \mathbb{E}|X−a| \leq \mathbb{E}(|X|+|a|)$

From linearity of expectation we know that: $\ \mathbb{E}|X|+\mathbb{E}|a|$

Therefore: $\mathbb{E}|X−a| \leq \mathbb{E}|X| + \mathbb{E}|a|$ and from here:

- form assumption we know that: $\mathbb{E}|X| < \infty$
- in general we know that: $\mathbb{E}|a|=|a|$ and $ |a| < \infty$ for $a \in \mathbb{R}$

I used help of @geetha290krm @Michael. Is that correct?

Comment: $|X-a| \leq |X| + |a|$

Comment: Thank you @Michael ! I will edit my question in a minute :)

Comment: @Michael bot how does it translate to pdf functions?

Comment: If a PDF of $X$ exists then we always have $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_X(x)dx=1$, regardless of whether or not $E[|X|]<\infty$.

Comment: So I shouldn't involve pdf in the proof? Just $\mathbb{E}|X-a| \leq \mathbb{E}(|X| + |a|) = \mathbb{E}|X| + \mathbb{E}|a|$ and from that: $\mathbb{E}|X| < \infty$ and $\mathbb{E}|a| = |a| < \infty$ for $a \in \mathbb{R}$. @Michael

Comment: Not all random variables have a pdf. Never use pdf's unless you are told that they exist.

Comment: @geetha290krm In most of basic probability courses , expectation is defined using a pdf or a pmf and all random variables are assumed to posses one of them. At most, at a beginner stage, one can define it using Stieltjes integral.Without the notion of measure theory, it is simply impossible to rigorously define expectation which itself is a Lebesgue integral. At a beginner level therefore, a proof using pdf and pmf separately is usually accepted as valid . Otherwise, monotonicity of expectation, needs to be stated as an independent unproved property and then it may be quoted in the problem.